# Checkbox/Button submit hide class/ID

Tags: php, html, css, checkbox

What I want to do is simple in words but I have no idea how to actually do it.

I have a Div ID/Class given to a container in an HTML file.

Now I want to add a checkbox or button in a php file which can hide and show the div element on HTML file.

What I want to do:

1. Normally vislble to everyone.
2. I checked hide open and clicked submit.
3. Remove the container or change the visibility to none.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right try this :
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show

just change buttons to checkbox, and do some checking, if checkbox is checked make hide else show

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#showHide').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? $("p").show() : $("p").hide();  
}); 
});
</script>


<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="showHide" name="showHide" value="Show">Check it
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Javascript (you don't have to use Jquery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(thediv){
   id = document.getElementById(thediv).style;
   id.display = (id.display != 'inline')? 'inline' : 'none';
}
</script>
```

Then define the div that you want to hide:

```
<div style="display:none" id="my_div">
     Hello World or any other HTML
</div>
```

Now - set your radio button some where in your code, and trigger the show script upon click:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="showHide('my_div')" />
```

If you want the div to be shown as default, change to

```
<div style="display:inline" id="my_div">
```

Or just completely remove the style.